# CasperJS hangs when processing big numerical loops

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

Even on a simple code, CasperJS seems to hang when presented with a big iteration number, for example:

```
function urlCheck(url) {
     // Thing to do with url
}

casper.start('https://www.exampleAPI.com', function() {
     console.log('Booted up first page.');
});

casper.then(function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 5000000; i++) {
        urlCheck('https://www.exampleAPI.com/api/id=' + i)
    };
});

casper.run();
```

It seems to be fine with anything within the first thousand - i.e. 4 digits long. Anything further than that, I would get the first 'Booting up...' message, but then the script hangs on processing the number. I've left a comp running for hours to test if it was just a processing time thing, but no cigar.

Any help would be super appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to avoid loading plugins and images? That would be an easy one:

```
    var casper = require('casper').create({
        pageSettings: {
            loadImages : false,
            loadPlugins : false,
        }
    });
```

Another option is to create new pages and close (cleanup) them again like descriped [here on github](http://github.com/n1k0/casperjs/pull/826#issuecomment-34950562)

Comment: Yeah, it's something about it processing the link quantity before starting the processes...